# How do I target specific nav bars that have an id?

Tags: css

This may be a dumb question, but I'm new to this so don't be cruel! (ha) Okay, I'm in a web design class and we are working on an assignment. I have three navigation bars on my web page and they all have an id name. topnav, mainnav, and footernav. They all have to look different. How do I target them individually? I've tried #topnav {whatever rules I add;} but that does nothing. I've tried .topnav {whatever rules;} and that also does nothing. I can't figure it out and I'm about to flip out! Please help me out. Thanks!! 
This is what it looks like:

```
<ul id="topnav"> 
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

That produces a little mini nav bar in my webpage that I have to center the text inside the button backgrounds, take out the underline, make the text bold, 12px, and green, and it has to have a red hover. I've almost got it... it's green, red hover, I cant figure out how to center it though or target that one particular nav bar with css. Everything I try either does nothing or targets them all (all navbars) 
When I put the rules in css this is what I've got:

```
a:link {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #4B5125;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I know a:link targets them all but I'm wanting to tell css that it needs to modify these links but ONLY these links, not all the navigation bars on the page. Also this doesn't center the text... This stuff is hard!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: I've also tried a:link {blah blah;} but that targets all of them!

Comment: We need to see the HTML / CSS and some idea of what it is you are trying to affect. Is it the navars or the links? It's not clear.

Comment: Is that better? I've edited my question. :)

Comment: What rules have you tried to apply? When you say "*nothing happened*" what were you expecting to happen? Are you trying to style the `<ul>`, the `<li>` or the `<a>` elements?

Comment: I've added them to my question. I'm trying to center the text, take out the underline, make them bold, 12px. and green. However css thinks that I'm talking about all of the links on the webpage and applies these rules to them all. I want to just edit the navbar with the id "topnav" and for some reason  #topnav does nothing even though I thought # was an id selector...

Comment: I guess I would be trying to style the <a> elements?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you need to appreciate, with CSS, is that certain elements don't automatically inherit certain properties from their ancestors; `<a>` elements in particular inherit neither `color` nor `text-decoration` by default (although if you apply the rules `color: inherit;` and `text-decoration: inherit;` they can be made to do so:

```css
#topnav {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#topnav li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: limegreen;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#topnav li a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topnav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ngo9w3Lq/).

And also the following, note that in this instance the `color` and `text-decoration` rules have been moved to the ancestor `#topnav` element (from the `<li>` as in the previous demo):inherit;` they can be made to do so:

```css
#topnav {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: limegreen;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#topnav li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#topnav li a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topnav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ngo9w3Lq/2).

This allows you ensure that all descendants – including `<a>` elements – will implement the same style as set on the closest ancestor element that specifies those styles. Obviously though a more specific selector targeting descendants will override a less-specific selector targeting an ancestor.

However, since you're setting those properties – `color` and `text-decoration` – on the `<a>` elements it may make more sense to define the specific colors and text-decoration on the `<a>` elements themselves — unless you specifically want to have multiple descendants styled in a common way.

If it is just the `<a>` elements you want to target then the following will achieve that:

```css
#topnav {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#topnav li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#topnav li a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topnav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ngo9w3Lq/3).

Now, in the comment to your question you explained that:

> I'm trying to center the text, take out the underline, make them bold, 12px. and green. However css thinks that I'm talking about all of the links on the webpage and applies these rules to them all. I want to just edit the navbar with the id "topnav" and for some reason #topnav does nothing even though I thought # was an id selector.

You're a little vague about centring the text; that could be interpreted as 'centred in the page' or 'centred in the `<li>` elements; above I've assumed that you wanted them centred in the page.

To centre the text in the page, you first style the `#topnav` element with the `text-align: center` rule; this aligns any inline – and inline-block – elements within that element; to further that we display the `<li>` elements as `display: inline-block`, which obviously causes them to be displayed as inline-block, and therefore centred by the above rule.

I've chosen to believe that you want all the text of the `#topnav` to be `12px` and `bold`, therefore those styles are applied to the `#topnav` element (these properties the `<a>` elements will typically inherit).

I think it's clear to observe that `#topnav` does, in fact, do something (rather than "*nothing*") but perhaps you were relying on inheritance incorrectly. As for styling the `<a>` elements it's not essential to style all the pseudo-classes of those elements (`:link`, `:visited`, `:hover`, `:active` and `:focus`) if you want the same style to be applied to all states; so common properties shared by all states should be in the rules for the `a`, properties unique to each of the pseudo-classes/'states' of the `<a>` elements would be typically placed in only the rules for that, or those, specific pseudo-classes.

A typical example is the following:

```
/* the common properties of all <a> elements, and those
   that match only the ':link' pseudo-class: */
a,
a:link {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
/* properties for the ':hover' state:
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #f90;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #f90;
}
/* properties for the ':active' and ':focus' state: */
a:active,
a:focus {
    color: #f00;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px #f00;
}
```

```css
/* the common properties of all <a> elements, and those
that match only the ':link' pseudo-class: */
a,
a:link {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

/* properties for the ':hover' state: */
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #f90;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #f90;
}

/* properties for the ':active' and ':focus' state: */
a:active,
a:focus {
  color: #f00;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #f00;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Link One</a>
<a href="#">Link Two</a>
<a href="#">Link Three</a>
```

Now, if you have some `<a>` elements in one element, and the same elements outside of that element, you need to adjust the selector to target only those elements within the specific element, in this the `#topnav` element; so for simple HTML such as the following:

```
<div id="topnav">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
</div>

<div id="sidenav">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
</div>

<a href="#">Other links 1</a>
<a href="#">Other links 2</a>
```

We could use a selector such as `a { /* css */}` to target all the `<a>` elements, or we could use a selector including the ancestor element-type to target only those `<a>` elements within a `<div>`, which would lead to: `div a` (or `div > a`), also we could specificy, by the `id` in this case, which specific `<div>` whose `<a>` descendants we wish to style: `#topnav a`:

```
/* All <a> elements: */
a {
  font-size: 2em;
}

/* All <a> elements inside of a <div>: */
div a,
div > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* All <a> elements inside of '#topnav': */
#topnav a {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```css
/* All <a> elements: */
a {
  font-size: 2em;
}

/* All <a> elements inside of a <div>: */
div a,
div > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* All <a> elements inside of '#topnav': */
#topnav a {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div id="topnav">
  <!-- these links will have a size of 2em (matching 'a'), without an underline (matching: 'div a' and 'div > a') and a color of #f90 (matching '#topnav a') -->
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</div>

<div id="sidenav">
  <!-- these links will be 2em (matching 'a'), and without an underline (matching 'div a', and 'div > a'): -->
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</div>

<!-- these links will be 2em (matching 'a'), with an underline (not matching 'div a, div > a'): -->
<a href="#">Other links 1</a>
<a href="#">Other links 2</a>
```

References:

- [CSS Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

Comment: Wow David! So much info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the links only inside `#topnav` using `descendant/child selector` i.e. setting a space between parent and child element in CSS selectors. [**Learn more about CSS Selectors**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

If you need to center the links, give the `ul` a fixed width and set `auto` margins `left` and `right`. The centering is way too simple now. You will learn more modern concepts like flexbox later.

```css
#topnav {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Short hand for margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; */
}
#topnav a:link { /* Access all the anchors inside ul#topnav using child selector */
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #4B5125;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topnav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="middlenav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul id="bottomnav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, however I can only edit my CSS. I'm not allowed to touch my html page unless told to. So I cant add the HTML code. I did use #topnav a:link and it targeted just my nav bar that I wanted so that's a plus... I'm getting closer. Now to center everything. :)

Comment: The HTML added was just to give you a demo that CSS rule I used does not target the other menus. You need not add them. If you want to center everything, wrap all the menus inside a container say `<div class="container">` and use `.container { width: 100px; margin: 0 auto; }` which is the repetition of what I did earlier for `ul`.

Comment: I don't think we are on the same page... or I'm making this way harder than it needs to be. Sorry for being so dumb about it, this is only my second class that deals with coding and I'm having a hard time grasping everything. Are you telling me to add the div class to my HTML? If so, I cant do that. We have to code everything with what we already have in HTML and figure a way to do it using only CSS unless the instructions say to add anything else to the HTML.

Comment: Hmmm I see. Maybe you can ask help from the instructor. When you run the Code snippet it actually centers the items. You will need to add your full HTML, CSS and use the code snippet inbuilt in question editor in order for us to help you.

Comment: Okay, thanks... I have class tonight at 6 so I'll just cry to the instructor. Haha... thanks for trying to help anyway! :)

Comment: You are welcome, Sylvia! :) Were you able to get some help? If not, check out David's comprehensive answer!